# json login session error

Tags: javascript, php, json

i used a json login data file to login with php. i used javascript to search any user in the json data file and show me page or redirect to login page.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#login').click(function () {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var pass = $('#pass').val();
        var error = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    if (email == value.email && pass == value.pass) {
                        error = false;
                    }
                });
                if (error == false) {
                    document.location = "index.php?email=" + email;
                } else {
                    $('#email').val('');
                    $('#pass').val('');
                    alert('please check your email or password!');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

this works fine. but i used to login with my url and it also access any email to my index.php file. how to make to this correct.

i type like this on url and it also shows me index file.

```
http://json.test/index.php?email=test123@gmail.com
```

i want to restrict this method and only login with json file data. can anyone know how to make php session with this JavaScript code.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I also must point out that this is not secure at all and having a login like this is almost redundant. Anyone can access the entire list of emails and passwords using the current code. Ideally, validation of login should happen on the server side and not on the client

Comment: You should `urlencode` the email you passed in the URL.

Comment: i tried this with php. it's not working properly

Comment: how to do urlencode

Comment: your issue is not clear. Why your loading url with email as para.

Comment: i fixed this. thanks for supporting all